# Выбор нескольких элементов из списка Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы, for

Столкнулся с маленькой проблемкой при написании кода: Нужно в цикле for пробежаться по нескольким возвратам функции одновременно, но при том цикл for должен быть один!

```
def Example():
    list1 = ['Данные и списка 1', 'Данные и списка 1', 'Данные и списка 1']
    list2 = ['Данные и списка 2', 'Данные и списка 2', 'Данные и списка 2']
    list3 = ['Данные и списка 3', 'Данные и списка 3', 'Данные и списка 3']
    return list1, list2, list3

all_lists = Example()

for i in all_lists:
    print(all_lists[0], all_lists[1], all_lists[2])
```

Ожидаемый Вывод: Данные и списка 1 Данные и списка 1 Данные и списка 1 Данные и списка 2 Данные и списка 2 Данные и списка 2 Данные и списка 3 Данные и списка 3 Данные и списка 3

буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: `print( * sum( all_lists, [] ) )`

Answer (score 2):

```py
from itertools import chain

for i in chain(*all_lists):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in sum(all_lists, []):
    print(i)
```

Другой вариант:

```
from functools import reduce

for i in reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, all_lists):
    print(i)
```

reduce в данном случае складывает все списки

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще так:

```
list1 = ['Данные и списка 1', 'Данные и списка 1', 'Данные и списка 1']
list2 = ['Данные и списка 2', 'Данные и списка 2', 'Данные и списка 2']
list3 = ['Данные и списка 3', 'Данные и списка 3', 'Данные и списка 3']

Соединяем списки простым оператором * 

result = [*list1,*list2,*list3]

Если вам нужен вывод в одну строку используйте end = ' '

for value in result:
    print(value, end = ' ')
```